# Order frequent XML Data by group using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `XDocument` with this data:

```
<item>
    <name>Name 1</name>
    <group>foo</group>
    ...
</item>
<item>
    <name>Name 2</name>
    <group>bar</group>
    ...
</item>
<item>
    <name>Name 3</name>
    <group>foo</group>
    ...
</item>
```

That means I have 2 items with `group` = foo and 1 item with `group` = bar. How can I order that data by the most frequent `group`? Result:

```
<item>
    <name>Name 1</name>
    <group>foo</group>
    ...
</item>
<item>
    <name>Name 3</name>
    <group>foo</group>
    ...
</item>
<item>
    <name>Name 2</name>
    <group>bar</group>
    ...
</item>
```

Data is loaded like this:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(@"\path\data.xml");
```

Comment: What is the question ? Can somebody do this thing for me ? Try google, there's lot of examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple `GroupBy` and `OrderByDescending`:

```
var items = xml.Root.Elements()
                    .GroupBy(r => r.Element("group").Value)
                    .OrderByDescending(r => r.Count())
                    .ToList();
```

Then simply remove all nodes and add them ordered:

```
xml.Root.RemoveAll();
xml.Root.Add(items);
```

Comment: Don't you need a `SelectMany` after the `OrderByDescending`?

Comment: @juharr No. You don't need a `SelectMany`.

Comment: This would result in a `List<IGrouping<..>>` element without the `SelectMany`.

Comment: @OmriAharon True, but it does not matter.

Comment: @sloth I see, the `XContainer.Add(object)` just handles it.  Nice.

Comment: @juharr Yes, `Add` is called recursive if its argument implements `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with objects instead of the xml, you'll first need to deserialize the `xml` into a `List<Item>`, where each `Item` is a class of the same structure in the xml.

After that, when you have the list you can use `GroupBy`:

```
var newList = list.GroupBy(i => i.Group)             //group together by "group" value
                  .OrderByDescending(i => i.Count()) //simple ordering
                  .SelectMany(i => i)                //flatten the hierarchy
                  .ToList();                         //back to list
```